# Is there a way of getting a value from inside a loop

Tags: c#, loops, csv, while-loop

I need to be able to return the final line of code `fleetVehicles.insertVehicle(vehicles[i])` however, I can't do this because it is nested in all the other loops.... I know the code isn't the best, however, it works how I need it to. Is there a way of getting that value out or do I need to rearrange all the loops? I am really stuck any answer would be helpful. The code is below.

Thank you kindly

```cs
void setUpVehicles(out Fleets fleetVehicles)
{
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(@"..\..\..\Data\data.csv"))
    {
        while (!stream.EndOfStream)
        {
            string lines = stream.ReadLine();
            string[] column = lines.Split(new char[] { ',' });

            string firstcolumn = (column[0]);
            string secondcolumn = (column[1]);

            var rentals_cost = File.ReadLines(@"..\..\..\Data\data2.csv");
            foreach (var line in rentals_cost)
            {
                 if (linee.Split(',')[0].Equals(firstcolumn))
                 {
                     string[] vehicles = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\..\Data\data1.csv").Where(line => !line.StartsWith(rego)).ToArray();
                     fleetVehicles = new Fleets();

                     for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.Length; i++)
                     {
                         fleetVehicles.insertVehicle(vehicles[i]);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Declare variable outside the loop?

Comment: Why do you create `new Fleets();` but do not persist it somewhere before the next foreach iteration starts?

Comment: Not the best method is an understatement. Imo, you should be reading the files only once. There for each line of Data.csv you read all Data1 then all Data2.
That make no sense. you should show example data from those file and clarify the link between them with few sentece. 
I will also advocate for using a 3rd party lib to read the CSV and project it to a List of custom object that way it will really ease the mapping and the join.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is stopping you from creating the Fleets object first and then filling it up inside the loop. This way you can return a Fleets object with this function:

```cs
Fleets setUpVehicles()
        {
            var fleetVehicles = new Fleets();
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(@"..\..\..\Data\data.csv"))
                {
                    while (!stream.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        {
                            string lines = stream.ReadLine();

                            string[] column = lines.Split(new char[] { ',' });

                            string firstcolumn = (column[0]);
                            string secondcolumn = (column[1]);

                            var rentals_cost = File.ReadLines(@"..\..\..\Data\data2.csv");
                            foreach (var line in rentals_cost)
                            {
                                // you had a little typo here
                                if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals(firstcolumn))
                                {
                                    string[] vehicles = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\..\Data\data1.csv").Where(line => !line.StartsWith(rego)).ToArray();


                                    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.Length; i++)
                                    {
                                        fleetVehicles.insertVehicle(vehicles[i]);

                                    }


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
                return fleetVehhicles;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to return last vehicle

```
string setUpVehicles(out Fleets fleetVehicles) {
 string returnValue = null;

 using(StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(@ "..\..\..\Data\data.csv")) {
  while (!stream.EndOfStream) {
   {
    string lines = stream.ReadLine();

    string[] column = lines.Split(new char[] {
     ','
    });

    string firstcolumn = (column[0]);
    string secondcolumn = (column[1]);

    var rentals_cost = File.ReadLines(@ "..\..\..\Data\data2.csv");
    foreach(var line in rentals_cost) {
     if (linee.Split(',')[0].Equals(firstcolumn)) {
      string[] vehicles = File.ReadAllLines(@ "..\..\..\Data\data1.csv").Where(line => !line.StartsWith(rego)).ToArray();
      fleetVehicles = new Fleets();

      for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.Length; i++) {
       fleetVehicles.insertVehicle(vehicles[i]);
       returnValue = vehicles[i];

      }


     }
    }
   }
  }


 }

 return returnValue;

}
```

Comment: This gives an error saying 'the out parameter"fleetVehicles" must be assigned to before control leaves the current method